# How do i get rid of this unwanted weight blending?

Tags: weight-painting

[image] I am making a minecraft character and trying to weight paint it using Born CGs minecraft tutorial as a guideline.  For the arm, there is only one section of vertices that are weighted in any way and they are marked in the picture.  They are all set to 1.00, which is displayed as red.  But for some reason, I have this weird blending going on, which adds yellow, green and blue at the ends of the red.  I don't want that!  I just want read and blue.  Why is it doing this and how do i stop it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colors in the middle of a poly show the average of the weights of the poly's vertices. When the top two verts in a quad have weight 1 and the bottom two have weight 0, you see this:

[image: Quad: red along the top (weight 1) verts, fading down to blue along the bottom (weight 0)]

This coloring shows you that if you move the pose bone for this group, the top verts will move which also pulls along the entire quad. Hence the whole quad is affected, so the whole quad is colored.

[image: Moving the top verts moves the whole poly]

This is probably what you want, but if it isn't, you need to [**Rip**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/vertex/rip_vertices.html#bpy-ops-mesh-rip-move) along the edge. Then you can paint the verts belonging to the upper quad 1 and the ones belonging to the lower one 0, and since there is no quad in between you won't see any unwanted blending. It will look like this, except I added a gap between the upper and lower quad so you can understand it better. In reality you'd have the each pair of verts right on top of each other.

[image: After ripping]

Note that when you move the pose bone for this group, the upper quad will move, but not the lower one, so it really will appear to "rip" apart.

Comment: ok, so it's just visual.  They must have added that later, because in borncgs tutorial it didn't do that (the video is old)  thanks for the help